# PostgreSQL: Hard code string in SQL

Tags: postgresql

How can I have a hard coded string in a PostgreSQL SELECT?

Something like:

```
SELECT
 'some value' As FieldName
 FROM table
```

Above give a error in pgAdmin.

Comment: Please edit your question and show the error that you are getting.  The only suspicious part of your query is the `from` clause.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

after the SELECT key word you can only insert a column name. Maybe you are looking for something like this

```
SELECT 'columnname' AS 'alias'
FROM 'tablename'
WHERE 'alias/columnname' = 'hardcodedvalue';
```

Comment: Identifiers (=alias) need to be put in double quotes, not single quotes. `as 'alias'` is invalid SQL. as is `'tablename'`

Comment: yes.... it was a quick example; alias/columnname is also invalid because the correct sintax is alias | columnname.

Answer (score 9):

Craig Ringers answer is (as always) correct I want to add the following extension to it:

```
--
-- This is how you can define a hardcoded value as column (here as the type 'text').
-- Instead of the explicit 'CAST(...)' call it's also possible to use the
-- '::text' short version.
--
-- NOTE-1: The short version or omitting the type completely might not
--         work in every SQL client (e. g. SquirrelSQL), while the
--         CAST(...) call is pretty safe.
--
-- NOTE-2: Please always use lower case column names!
--
SELECT CAST('some value' AS text) AS fieldname;
```

Comment: is'nt PostgreSQL capable of determining the correct type ?

Answer (score 3):

What you wrote is fine, assuming that `table` actually exists. Try:

```
SELECT 'some_value' AS FieldValue, x FROM generate_series(1,10) x;
```

as an example that'll definitely work, printing the constant string out 10 times along with the counter.

If you want *just* a constant, not a constant column added to a select from a table, omit the `FROM` clause.

```
SELECT 'some value' AS FieldName;
```

will return a single-row result with a single column.

Comment: it might need casting depending on the query complexity: `select  'some value' :: TEXT       AS field_name,`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

SELECT * FROM table WHERE FieldName = 'some value';

It will select all columns from `table` where the value of `FieldName` is `'some value'`.

Answer (score 0):

no, it is not working inside procedure, getting below error while executing below query -

```
select  'some value' :: TEXT AS field_name;
```

ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function test_variable() line 8 at SQL statement
SQL state: 42601

Comment: Hi @Div, this doesn't seem to be an answer, but instead additional information to clarify the question? It might be more helpful to add this as an edit to the question instead of posting it as an answer.